# Is any question requiring knowledge of legal principles on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am asking this question in reference to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/39304/917).

So as to the general rule, is a question that requires knowledge of legal principles or ideas on topic even though law is not the central part of the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is not about the law, legal process or legal professions as determined by previous meta discussions and the FAQ/help centre, it isn't on-topic here.

That question in particular is clearly about the meaning of a regular English idiom. That it was used in a legal context doesn't bring it within scope of this site, any more than the use of numbers in a law would make the meaning of a mathematical equation on-topic.